# TypeError: URL constructor: /account is not a valid URL

Tags: typescript, authentication, next.js, typeerror, appwrite

I am developing a social media app with appwrite and nextjs, but as soon as I load the website I am getting "TypeError: URL constructor: /account is not a valid URL"
Here is the file structure of my app:
[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak93y.jpg)

---

Here is the layout.tsx file of the main app directory

```
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import './globals.css'
import { QueryProvider } from './lib/queries/QueryProvider'
import AuthProvider from './context/AuthContext'
import { Toaster } from '@/components/ui/toaster'


export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Janadh',
  description: 'The Social Media of Education',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
          <QueryProvider>
            <AuthProvider>
        {children}
        <Toaster />
            </AuthProvider>
          </QueryProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

---

Here is the app/lib/appwrite/api.ts:

```
import { INewUser } from "@/app/types";
import { ID, Query } from "appwrite";
import { account, appwriteConfig, avatars, databases } from "./config";

export async function createUserAccount(user: INewUser) {
  try {
    const newAccount = await account.create(
      ID.unique(),
      user.email,
      user.password,
      user.name
    );

    if (!newAccount) throw Error;

    const avatarUrl = avatars.getInitials(user.name);

    const newUser = await saveUserToDB({
      accountId: newAccount.$id,
      name: newAccount.name,
      email: newAccount.email,
      username: user.username,
      imageUrl: avatarUrl,
    });

    return newUser;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

export async function saveUserToDB(user: {
  accountId: string;
  email: string;
  name: string;
  imageUrl: URL;
  username?: string;
}) {
  try {
    const newUser = await databases.createDocument(
      appwriteConfig.databaseId,
      appwriteConfig.userCollectionId,
      ID.unique(),
      user
    );

    return newUser;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}


export async function signInAccount(user: { email: string; password: string }) {
  try {
    const session = await account.createEmailSession(user.email, user.password);

    return session;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

export async function getCurrentUser() {
  try {
    const currentAccount = await account.get();

    if (!currentAccount) throw Error;

    const currentUser = await databases.listDocuments(
      appwriteConfig.databaseId,
      appwriteConfig.userCollectionId,
      [Query.equal("accountId", currentAccount.$id)]
    );

    if (!currentUser) throw Error;

    return currentUser.documents[0];
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

export async function signOutAccount() {
  try {
    const session = await account.deleteSession("current");

    return session;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Here is the config.ts file:
`

```
import { Client, Account, Databases, Storage, Avatars } from 'appwrite';

interface AppwriteConfig {
    url: string;
    projectId: string;
    databaseId: string;
    storageId: string;
    userCollectionId: string;
    // postCollectionId: string;
}

export const appwriteConfig: AppwriteConfig = {
    url: process.env.APPWRITE_URL || '',
    projectId: process.env.APPWRITE_PROJECT_ID || '',
    databaseId: process.env.APPWRITE_DATABASE_ID || '',
    storageId: process.env.APPWRITE_STORAGE_ID || '',
    userCollectionId: process.env.APPWRITE_USER_COLLECTION_ID || '',
    // postCollectionId: process.env.APPWRITE_POST_COLLECTION_ID || '',
};

export const client = new Client();

client.setProject(appwriteConfig.projectId);
client.setEndpoint(appwriteConfig.url);

export const databases = new Databases(client);
export const account = new Account(client);
export const storage = new Storage(client);
export const avatars = new Avatars(client);
```

Here is the Query Provider file(app/lib/queries/QueryProvider.tsx

```
'use client'
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { ReactNode } from 'react';

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

export const QueryProvider = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode}) => {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        {children}
    </QueryClientProvider>
  )
}
```

Here is the Queries and Mutations file(app/lib/queries/queriesAndMutation):

```
import { INewUser } from "@/app/types"
import { createUserAccount, signInAccount, signOutAccount } from "../appwrite/api"
import{
    useQuery,
    useMutation,
    useQueryClient,
    useInfiniteQuery,
} from '@tanstack/react-query'


// Unlike queries, mutations are typically used to create/update/delete data or perform server side-effects. For this purpose, TanStack Query exports a useMutation hook.
export const useCreateUserAccount = () => {
    return useMutation({
        mutationFn: (user: INewUser) => createUserAccount(user)
    })
}

export const useSignInAccount = () => {
    return useMutation({
        mutationFn: (user: { 
            email: string; 
            password: string;
        }) => signInAccount(user)
    })
}

export const useSignOutAccount = () => {
    return useMutation({
        mutationFn: signOutAccount
    });
}
```

Here is the AuthContext file (app/context/AuthContext.tsx):

```
'use client';
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { IContextType, IUser } from "../types";
import { getCurrentUser } from "../lib/appwrite/api";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";


export const INITIAL_USER = {
  id: "",
  name: "",
  username: "",
  email: "",
  imageUrl: "",
  bio: "",
};

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  user: INITIAL_USER,
  isLoading: false,
  isAuthenticated: false,
  setUser: () => {},
  setIsAuthenticated: () => {},
  checkAuthUser: async () => false as boolean,
};

const AuthContext = createContext<IContextType>(INITIAL_STATE);

const AuthProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<IUser>(INITIAL_USER);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  const navigate = useRouter();

  const checkAuthUser = async () => {
    try {
      const currentAccount = await getCurrentUser();

      if (currentAccount) {
        setUser({
          id: currentAccount.$id,
          name: currentAccount.name,
          username: currentAccount.username,
          email: currentAccount.email,
          imageUrl: currentAccount.imageUrl,
          bio: currentAccount.bio,
        });

        setIsAuthenticated(true);

        return true;
      }

      return false;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return false;
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (
      localStorage.getItem("cookieFallback") === "[]" ||
      localStorage.getItem("cookieFallback") === null
    )
      navigate.push("/login");

    checkAuthUser();
  }, []);

  const value = {
    user,
    setUser,
    isLoading,
    isAuthenticated,
    setIsAuthenticated,
    checkAuthUser,
  };

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};

export default AuthProvider;

export const useUserContext = () => useContext(AuthContext);
```

If you want more code you can ask me

I have tried with configuring appwrite, Eslint, Typescript, Still can't resolve this error. Changed many things, but can't fix it. Please help me with this error, I bet when this app will be created it will help you too a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur if the Appwrite endpoint is set incorrectly. The format for the endpoint must be `https://<HOSTNAME>/v1` (`http` or `https` can vary).

Here's an example of a correct endpoint: `https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1`

Comment: Thank You for your response, but the error is not resolved! And I have double checked the endpoints!